# Flow and React.createRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I am trying to add some dank Flow typings to my React app. I have two components, one which references the other to trigger some validation. A very simplified version looks kind of like this:

```
class FormFields extends React.Component {
  onSubmit = () => {/* impl */};
  render() {/* impl */}
}

class Form extends React.Component {
  formRef = React.createRef();
  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.formRef.current.onSubmit();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <FormFields ref={this.formRef} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm trying to add typings so that `this.formRef.current.onSubmit` is typed and autocompleted. How do I do that? [There are some docs on the subject](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/refs/), but those only apply to the "old" way of making refs, with functions.

I notice that React's exporting [the following type definition](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/react.js#L231-L232) for `React.createRef`:

```
declare export function createRef<ElementType: React$ElementType>(): 
{current: null | React$ElementRef<ElementType>};
```

I'm pretty inexperienced with Flow, so the solution is probably something pretty straight forward.

Comment: This should work: `formRef: React.ElementRef<HTMLFormElement> = React.createRef();` (not tested). Or even `formRef = React.createRef<HTMLFormElement>();`

Comment: Unfortunately, none of those work.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: when you call `React.createRef`, you get an object that has the form `{ current: theActualRef }`, as you can tell from React's type definition. Therefore, your first example won't work. The second example I'd assume would work if I switched out the HTMLFormElement with my component `FormFields`, but instead it throws the error `Unexpected token )` for the last parenthesis in the line `formRef = React.createRef<EditBrukerForm>();`

Comment: So just type it as `formRef: { current: React.ElementRef<WhatEverElement> | null }`